# PHP Scheduled Task with Windows Authentication

Tags: php, sql-server, database-connection, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008

I am working on an PHP application hosted on Windows Server 2008. Sorry if some informations are not clear but this work has been made by another developer and I can not contact him.

There is a scheduled task executed every week to synchronize some data from a SQL Server database on another server (I do not have access to this other server).

The scheduled task runs a .bat file :

```
start C:\...\php.exe E:\...\synchro.php
```

But the script cannot connect to the database :

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'
```

When I run my PHP script from command line, like this :

```
php E:\...\synchro.php
```

... everything is working.

In my synchro.php file, the connection to the database is made like this :

```
$connectionInfo = array('Database'=> $database);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

I think it is using Windows Authentication because there is no login/password.

In the scheduled task properties, the following options are checked :

- "Run whether user is logged on or not"
- "Do not store password. The task will only have to access to local
  computer resources."

And in "When running the task, use the following user account" there is the current account.

I don't understand why it works when running the PHP script in command line but not from the scheduled task.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks in advance (and sorry if my English is not perfect ^_^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem :

In the tasks properties, the option "Do not store password" was checked. Without this option, everything works.